# How to manage Apache-Beam TextIO exceptions into failures?

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

How to convert TextIO exceptions into failures?
Sometimes when i use TextIO.read() I have

> org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec:
> src/test/resources/config/qqqqqqq
> How to separate exceptions to independent list of failures?
> For example this code:
> I have a file with list of other files and need to read all lines from all files as one list

```
   PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    PCollection<String> lines = pipeline           
            .apply(TextIO.read().from("src/test/resources/config/W-PSFV-LOG-FILE-2022-05-16_23-59-59.txt"))
            .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(line -> "src/test/resources/config/" + line))
            .apply(TextIO.readAll());
    ;
    lines.apply(Log.ofElements());
    pipeline.run();
```

But if one of files is broken it throws FileNotFoundException and stops. Do not want to stop, I want to get a list of all existing files and list with broken files

Answer (score 2):

I thinks you can use a dead letter queue in order to solve your problem.

Beam proposes natively error handling with `TupleTags` or `exceptionInto` and `exceptionVia` methods in `MapElements`.

It then returns a `Result` structure with good outputs PCollections and failures PCollection.

You can also use a library called `Asgarde` :

https://github.com/tosun-si/asgarde

```java
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> lines = pipeline           
            .apply(TextIO.read().from("src/test/resources/config/W-PSFV-LOG-FILE-2022-05-16_23-59-59.txt"))

    WithFailures.Result<PCollection<String>, Failure> result = CollectionComposer.of(lines)
            .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(line -> "src/test/resources/config/" + line));
    ;

   // Gets outputs and Failure PCollections.
   PCollection<String> output = result.output();
   PCollection<Failure> failures = result.failures();
   
   // Then you can sink your Failures in database, GCS file or topic if needed...
   ......
    
    pipeline.run();
```

`Failure` object is proposed by `Asgarde` library and give the current input element as String and exception :

```java
public class Failure implements Serializable {
    private final String pipelineStep;
    private final String inputElement;
    private final Throwable exception;
```

If you want to use this code, you have to import Asgarde library, for example with Maven in your pom.xml file :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.groupbees</groupId>
    <artifactId>asgarde</artifactId>
    <version>0.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or with Gradle :

```
implementation group: 'fr.groupbees', name: 'asgarde', version: '0.19.0'
```

PS : I am the creator of `Asgarde` library, the Readme of project shows many examples to apply `Dead letter queue` with native `Beam` and with `Asgarde` library.

Don't hesitate to read the Readme file of the project : https://github.com/tosun-si/asgarde

Comment: Sorry, but the code provided by you just cannot be compiled:

 `WithFailures.Result<PCollection<String>, Failure> result = CollectionComposer.of(lines)
            .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(line -> "src/test/resources/config/" + line));`


with error :

`Cannot resolve method 'apply(MapElements<NewInputT, String>)'`

Comment: If you want to use this code, you have to import Asgarde library, I edited the first post to explain, how to import it.

Comment: Thanks for  Asgarde.
Can't use it, because big project  already have own solution like this.
Is it possible to call  `TEXTIO.read()/radall()` inside  MapElements .via()
and catch the exception in `result.failures();`?

> all exceptions need to be catched by error manager
and use transforms not doFn

Comment: I think you can't use `TEXTIO.read().readAll()` in a `MapElements` because TextIO.read is an input connector.

`MapElements` is a native component that apply a transformation, behind the scene it's equivalent to a `ParDo` with `DoFn`.

Comment: if your files are not big, maybe you can write the logic that read your file from path in a `ParDo` and `DoFn` and in this logic, you can apply error handling.

It's not recommended if files are bigs, because your transformation is computed inside a worker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FileIO first to split the files into readable-existing files and non-existing files.

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> categoryAndFiles = p
     .apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("hdfs://path/to/*.gz"))
      // withCompression can be omitted - by default compression is detected from the filename.
     .apply(FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(GZIP))
     .apply(MapElements
         // uses imports from TypeDescriptors
         .into(kvs(strings(), strings()))
         .via((ReadableFile f) -> {
           try {
             f.open();
             return KV.of(
                 "readable-existing",
                 f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString());
           } catch (IOException ex) {
             return KV.of(
                 "non-existing",
                 f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString());
           }
         }));
```

Adapted from an [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L135).

Comment: It is very easy in the end:
```} catch(Exception e){
                  throw new RuntimeException("error"+e);                         
                          } ```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Rule
public transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

@Test
  public void testTransformWithIOException3() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PCollection<String> digits = pipeline.apply(Create.of("1", "2", "3"));

    WithFailures.Result<PCollection<String>, Failure> result = pipeline
            .apply("Read ", Create.of("1", "2", "3")) // PCollection<String>
            .apply("Map", new PTransform<PCollection<String>, WithFailures.Result<PCollection<String>, Failure>>() {
              @Override
              public WithFailures.Result<PCollection<String>, Failure> expand(PCollection<String> input) {
                return CollectionComposer.of(input)
                        .apply("//", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(s -> {
                          try {
                            if (s.equals("2")) throw new FileNotFoundException();                             
                            else
                              return s.toString();
                          } catch(Exception e){
                            throw new RuntimeException("error ");
                          }
                        }))
                        .getResult();
              }
            });

    result.output().apply("out",
            MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(x -> {
              System.out.println(x);
              return x.toString();
            }));

    result.failures().apply("failures",
            MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(x -> {
              System.out.println(x);
              return x.toString();
            }));
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```